# How do i sort MediaQuery's artistQuery Array alphabetically in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray

In my app , i load Artist and enter in `arrayOfArtists` and show in `UITableView`.

So i need to index to my `UITableView`.That's why i need to sort of my artist array in alphabetically like iOS Built-in Music App.

[image]

like above photo , it can be index to `UITableView` with `Title`.

So i need to sort my Artist Array in alphabetically.

How can i do that?

Here is some code that i load Artist from iPodLibrary.

in `ViewDidLoad`

```
    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
    query.groupingType = MPMediaGroupingAlbumArtist;
    self.arrayOfArtist = [query collections];
```

In `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[self.arrayOfArtist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]];
```

in `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return 1;
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [self.arrayOfArtist count];
}
```

And i want to show `TitleHeader` of `UITableView` alphabetical to index my `UITableView`.
How can i do that?
Thank guys.

Comment: Refer this blog this will help you. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/

Answer (score 3):

Sort using selector alphabetically:

```
NSArray *sortedArray=[self.arrayOfArtist sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: and how can i show that letter in TitleHeader of UITableView?

Comment: what letter? that selected string of artist?

Comment: no bro . i want to do like above image sorting under TitleLetter

Answer (score 1):

X-Developer-X -

I got something almost identical to what you want by implementing

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

sectionIndexTitlesForTableView produces the index characters on the right edge of the screen, and titleForHeaderInSection produces the headers between the sections. I have attached a screen capture of the results. I'm sure it could be made completely identical by changing some GUI settings in the table view. The differences I see are that my header bars are somewhat transparent and the characters in them are white.

[image: A screen capture that reveals my unusual tastes in music:]